# What is the best way to send a notification when user is locked out in Laravel Auth?

Tags: laravel, events, lockout

I want to send an email notification whenever a user reaches the maximum allowed login attempts (i.e. user is locked out).

What would be the best way to do this?
I see a fireLockoutEvent method in the ThrottlesLogins class, should I be listening for that event? And where should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create a listener for the event `LockoutEvent`.

```
php artisan make:listener LockoutEventListener
```

The **LockoutEventListener.php** is created under the folder `app/Listeners/LockoutEventListener`. Then register the `LockoutEvent` listener to the application in `app/providers/EventServiceProvider.php`.

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $listen = [
    ...
     'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LockoutEventListener',
    ],
];
```

Then update the handler method of the event `LockoutEvent`.

**LockoutEventListener.php**

```
public function handle($event)
{
    if ($event->request->has('email')) {
        $user = User::where('email', $event->request->input('email'))->first();
        if ($user && !$attemptEmailSent) {
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(...);
        }
    }
}
```